# io.socket is undefined inside function declaration, defined outside it

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, sails.js

So I'm trying to use io.socket to make a POST call to some controller action. The strange thing is that, when I use `io.socket.someMethod()` inside script tags like such, it works fine:

```
<script>
io.socket.post('/visualization/star', { id: visualID }, function (resData, jwres) {
  var star = document.getElementById("star-" + visualID.toString());
  if (star.className == "gold-star glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty md") {
    star.className = "grey-star glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty md";
  } else {
    star.className = "gold-star glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty md";
  }
});
</script>
```

But putting it inside a function declaration renders `io.socket` to be `undefined`:

```
<script>
function starVisual(visualID) {
  io.socket.post('/visualization/star', { id: visualID }, function (resData, jwres) {
    var star = document.getElementById("star-" + visualID.toString());
    if (star.className == "gold-star glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty md") {
      star.className = "grey-star glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty md";
    } else {
      star.className = "gold-star glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty md";
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

Putting `alert(io.socket)` outside the function declaration results in an object, while putting it on the first line inside the function declaration results in `undefined`.

I've also tried `window.io.socket`, but that results in the same thing. The JS file `sails.io.js` is included and loaded properly at the beginning, when the page first loads through my `layouts.ejs`. Also tried doing `<script>window.io = io</script>` to no avail.

I'm putting it inside a function declaration so that I can use it as part of my `onclick` attribute upon clicking an icon:
`<td class="star-wrap"><span id="star-<%= visualization.id %>" class="grey-star glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty md" onclick="starVisual(<%= visualization.id %>).bind(this);"></span></td>`

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone runs into this problem, for future reference, I solved this problem by doing the following:

```
<script>
window.socket = socket.io
function starVisual(visualID) {
io.socket.post('/visualization/star', { id: visualID }, function (resData, jwres) {
  var star = document.getElementById("star-" + visualID.toString());
  if (star.className == "gold-star glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty md") {
    star.className = "grey-star glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty md";
  } else {
    star.className = "gold-star glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty md";
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've setup my functions like yours and everything seems happy.

The problem may be a race condition. The `sails.io` script is loaded at the bottom of the body (make sure you place your scripts under that). If you `console.log()` anything before the scripts loads, you will get undefined errors.

Comment: Actually, since I needed it to load earlier, I manually loaded the script at the top of my layouts.ejs instead of using Grunt to autoload it at the end. I did find the solution in the Sails IRC last night: use ````window.socket = io.socket```` in the same script tags but outside the script declaration, and then use ````window.socket.post````.